# HighStock don't take my JSON data

Tags: php, json

Days ago i discovered HighStock. I want to use Data from SQL-database. Via php i read out the information and i echo it in JSON-style

Here is the script

```
<?php
include ("dbverbindung.php");
echo "[";
$sql = "SELECT time, amperage FROM pikkertonnode_44664399";
$erg = mysql_query($sql);
while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($erg))
{
if ($data['amperage'] == "") $data['amperage'] = 0;
echo "[".$data['time'].",".$data['amperage']."],"   ;
}
echo "]";    ?>
```

The output looks so:

```
[[1264978800000,68],[1264978805000,50],[1264978810000,61],[1264978815000,54]]
```

Is this correct?

Comment: That is valid JSON. However, HighStock may require a certain root format, i.e. object vs array.

Comment: Please, don't create the JSON string yourself!  Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: If you are echoing the json, how can you be passing it to a call somewhere? Show the code where you make the call.

Comment: That array looks like how HighStock [wants it to be](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json).  What does the HighStock code look like?  Where is this array being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem was that Highchart/Highstock don't take Strings. JSONdata was correct produced

e.g. [["123","12"],["123","12"],["123","12"]]

But thats useless with the ""

The code should look like

```
while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($erg)){
if ($data['amperage'] == ""){
    $data['amperage'] = 0;
}
$x = $data['time'];
$y = $data['amperage'];

$json[] = array( (int($x), int($y) );
}
```

And now i have the code I want .. Highstock now works perfectly

[[123,12],[123,12],[123,12]]

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
include ("dbverbindung.php");
echo "[";
$sql = "SELECT time, amperage FROM pikkertonnode_44664399";
$erg = mysql_query($sql);
$temp_array=array();
while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($erg))
{
array_push(temp_array,data);
}
echo json_encode($temp_array);   // make json data
?>
```

Both the formats are correct..

```
{                                 [
  {'1264978800000':'68'},           [1264978800000,68],
  {'1264978805000':'50'},           [1264978805000,50],
  {'1264978810000':'61'},           [1264978810000,61],
  {'1264978815000':'54'}            [1264978815000,54], 
}                                 ]
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.  It should be wrapped in `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: Your code won't produce the json that you gave. It will produce objects with `time` and `amperage` keys.

Comment: @MrCode - its correction of john's data ,its sample ,it is not coming from the code.

Comment: The sample JSON in the question is valid.

Comment: @sourcecode, that's a bad JSON example, for a start HighStock wants an array of values, why is `1264978800000` a key? Secondly your JSON switches format half way through. Finally, you need to use double quotes for valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

My code  now

    <?php
    ...   
    while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($erg))
    { if ($data['amperage'] == "") $data['amperage'] = 0;
    $array[] = array( $data['time'],$data['amperage']); }
    $json = json_encode($array);
    echo $json; ?>


When i open php-file it looks like:

    [["1264978800000","68"],["1264978805000","50"],["1264978810000","61"]]

So no {}

Comment: @MrCode,rocket - you both are right.so i edited my answer . :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating the JSON, you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).  Just make the array how you want it, then have PHP encode it.

```
<?php
include ("dbverbindung.php");
$sql = "SELECT time, amperage FROM pikkertonnode_44664399";
$erg = mysql_query($sql);

$json = array();
while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($erg)){
    if ($data['amperage'] == ""){
        $data['amperage'] = 0;
    }

    $json[] = array($data['time'], $data['amperage']);
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```